# How to remove the margin of the command `\includegraphics[options]{name}`?

Tags: pdfpages, includegraphics, tikz-node

Just like the picture below, I have a pdf page that its width is 6.32 inch and its height is 8.18 inch, and I used `tikz` making a rectangle which has the same width and height as the pdf page in standalone, then import the pdfpage in the document, however, it shows a margin around the page. How can I remove the margin?
[image]

The following is a mwe.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (6.32 in,8.18 in);% edge of the page
\node at (0.5*6.32 in,0.5*8.18 in) {\includegraphics[width=6.32 in]{titlepage.pdf}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: We can't replicate your screenshot as we don't have access to your [?] file `titlepage.pdf`.  Does the file `titlepage.pdf` maybe contain some whitespace along the edges?

Comment: Oh, I can’t upload file here, but it’s just an example, the file doesn’t have a white edge. You can use tikz drawing a black rectangle which has the same width and the same height as the file and create a pdf document, then import the pdf like the new above, you will find that it has a white edge.

Comment: Perhaps you can comment or delete the line starting with \draw...

Comment: try `\draw[use as bounding box]`, or set in the node the inner sep to 0pt, `\node[inner sep=0pt]`.

Comment: Thank you very much! The problem has been solved

Comment: Is there a reason you use a TikZ diagram to insert a graphics? Just for the border around it? You don't need TikZ for that. We can do this with `\fbox`. Even with TikZ, the following would do `\tikz[inner sep=+.5\pgflinewidth]\node[draw]{\includegraphics[width=6.32in]{titlepage.pdf}};`. This draws a border around the graphic without covering it partly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set in the node the inner sep to 0pt, `\node[inner sep=0pt]`.

Comment by Ulrike Fischer is the right answer.

The question has been solved.